# Is there a convention, law or axiom for associate operators when is a lack of brackets?

Tags: abstract-algebra, operator-theory

If a have an operator $\circledast:A\times A\rightarrow A$ and $a,b,c\in A$, then the expression
$$a\circledast b\circledast c$$
Can be interpreted only as  $(a\circledast b)\circledast c$ or is possible to interprete it as $a\circledast (b\circledast c)$?

Regardless if $\circledast$ is a associative or nonassociative operator.

And no matter if it's seen by a left-to-right reader (as a japanese person) or a right-to-left reader (as an english person).

Comment: Having an associative operator exactly means that it doesn't matter in which order you take the brackets

Comment: Sorry, I wrote commutative instead of associative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\circledast$ is not associative then in general 
$$a\circledast (b\circledast c) \neq (a\circledast b)\circledast c$$
so just writing 
$$a\circledast b\circledast c$$
would be ambiguous, unless we follow some convention of right of left associativity. As far as I know, when you see something like $a\circledast b\circledast c$ the operator $\circledast$ is taken to be associative, otherwise brackets would be added. So that means that you can then take $a\circledast (b\circledast c) $ or $(a\circledast b)\circledast c$ because these two are equal by associativity.

Comment: I got it but, is this "convention of right of left associativity" is followed by everyone, no matter culture? American, European, Asian, African, etc...

Comment: I think there is no agreed upon convention. Therefore, always put brackets if the operator is not associative, and when there are no brackets we may assume that the operator is associative unless explicitly stated otherwise.

Comment: So, let's say that an asian could take $a\circledast (b\circledast c)$ as a default convention to its culture when there is a lack of brackets? While an american can take $(a\circledast b)\circledast c $ instead.

Comment: Everyone can take it to mean whatever they would like of course and maybe there are local conventions. However, These conventions are not well known. The usual convention is with the brackets in case of non associativity and no brackets otherwise. People can always use conventions that are not standard or known, but then it is their fault because this will confuse the reader. In the same way someone could interpret $1+ 3*5$ as $(1+3)*5$, maybe this is a convention somewhere. However it is no convention that is widely known and not really accepted anywhere

Comment: In all the literature I've ever encountered as a working mathematician, brackets are *never* dropped when working with a nonassociative operator.

Comment: So, no matter what, if the operator is nonassociative, then we have to place the brackets... but if I'm find this in a text, then I can interprete it as my local convention.

Comment: I would say that if you encounter no brackets you would be safe to assume that the operator is associative. Otherwise the author of what you are reading should have explicitly said the operator is not necessarily associative and explained whether left or right associativity is assumed.

Comment: In the case of a division over real numbers, it's nonassociative and yet we find examples of questions like this: $4\div2\div2$.

Comment: Well that would be an example of a completely ambiguous question. Unless the author prescribed right or left associativity there is no correct answer to this question, and thus the question is flawed. So I would classify this as bad writing. No reader could make proper sense of this due to no fault of their own

Comment: @Branimir: $6-3-2=1$. We also drop brackets when involving two different operators that don't associate; e.g. $1 + 2 \cdot 3 = 7$.

Comment: You're absolutely right. When I hear the word nonassociative, I'm afraid I automatically complete it with the word algebra...

Answer (score 3):

Even though your answer has already been answered, it's important to notice that your expression doesn't make sense unless
$$
\circledast: A\times A\times A \to A.
$$
In this case, associativity doesn't matter and you can write $a\circledast b\circledast c$.

On the other hand, if your operation is defined as $\circledast:A\times A\to A$, something like $a\circledast b \circledast c$ isn't even defined *a priori* until you define the associativity.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to place $A\times A\rightarrow A $, instead of what I wrote. I change it in the question.